# Cast int (*a)[4] to int *p

Tags: c

Is it legal to cast a pointer to an array of ints to an int pointer?

```
int arr[4];
int (*a)[4] = &arr; 
int *p = (int*)a;
```

Comment: What does your compiler say about this?

Comment: Incidentally, the easy and correct way to get an `int *` here is simply `int *p = arr;` or `int p = *a;`. Each of `arr` and `*a` is an array of four `int`, and, when used in this way, it will be automatically converted to a pointer to its first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the original pointer's initialized to either `NULL` or a valid pointer to an `int[4]`, then yes. Pointer casts must not violate alignment requirements lest you get [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). A cast such as what I've described won't violate such requirement  ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶f̶u̶r̶t̶h̶e̶r̶m̶o̶r̶e̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶w̶i̶l̶l̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶u̶s̶a̶b̶l̶e̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶d̶e̶r̶e̶f̶e̶r̶e̶n̶c̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶b̶e̶c̶a̶u̶s̶e̶ ̶i̶f̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶`̶i̶n̶t̶(̶*̶a̶)̶[̶4̶]̶`̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶v̶a̶l̶i̶d̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶n̶o̶n̶n̶u̶l̶l̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ ̶i̶n̶d̶e̶e̶d̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶a̶n̶ ̶`̶i̶n̶t̶`̶ ̶a̶t̶ ̶`̶(̶i̶n̶t̶*̶)̶a̶`̶.

If you feel uneasy about pointer casts (as you should), you can effect the conversion in this case without casting by simply doing `*a` (will get `int[4]` which will decay to `int*`) or `a[0]` or `&a[0][0]` or `&(*a)[0]`. That way, you can also dereference the result while adhering to the letter of the standard.

Comment: Re “it will be usable for dereferencing”: This is incorrect; the C standard does not guarantee the result of such a cast is usable for dereferencing. Pointer conversions are specified in C 2018 6.3.2.3. Paragraph 7 says that a pointer to an object type can indeed be converted to a pointer to another object type, provided the alignment is correct. However, it does not guarantee what the **value** resulting from the conversion is, except that converting it back to the original type yields something equivalent to the original value. (Except certain guarantees are made for character pointers.)…

Comment: … Since different types of pointers can have different representations, it is permitted by the C standard that converting some `foo *` to some `bar *` may yield a bunch of bits that can be converted back to the `foo *` but that have no useful meaning as a `bar *`. So the C standard does not give us any guarantee that an `int (*)[4]` converted to an `int *` can be used to access an `int`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That's such an overly pedantic interpretation but I got to respect your language lawyering here. +1 All the more reason to avoid the cast, as I suggested in the second paragraph. I'd delete this but can't because it was marked accepted.

Comment: You can edit; feel free to take/adapt from my answer.

Comment: Re “overly pedantic”: Is it? Consider this. The standard says if you convert to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest address byte of the object. It says a suitably converted structure pointer points to its first member, and vice-versa. It says lvalue conversion results in the stored value. For integers, it says, if the value can be represented in the new type, the result is the unchanged value, and it then describes other cases. But for results of general object pointer conversions, it is silent other than about converting back. That seems like a deliberate omission.

Comment: @EricPostpischil When it comes to language lawyering, overly pedantic is the right amount of pedantic. I fully agree with your interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

C 2018 6.3.2.3 7 says we can convert an `int (*)[4]` to an `int *`:

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined…

The alignment is necessarily correct since an array of `int` must have the alignment required for an `int`.

However, the only thing the C standard says about the **value** resulting from this conversion is:

> … when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

This means that an `int *` can temporarily hold the value of an `int (*)[4]`. If we execute:

```
int arr[4];
int (*x)[4] = &arr;
int *y = (int *) x;
int (*z)[4] = (int (*)[4]) y;
```

then we know `x == z` is true because the standard tells us that. But we do not know what `y` is. Because the standard permits different types of pointers to have different representations (use the bits that represent their values in different ways), it is possible that `y` has no useful meaning as an `int *`. The C standard does not say the converted pointer can be used to access objects.

Most C implementations either support this deliberately or as an artifact of how they are designed. However, in terms of what the C standard specifies, no guarantee is given.